# How to tell hadoop how much memory to allocate to a single mapper job?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I've created a Elastic MapReduce job, and I'm trying to optimize its performance.

At this moment I'm trying to increase the number of mappers per instance. I am doing this via mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=X

```
elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --num-instance 3 \
 --bootstrap-action s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop \
 --args -s,mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=5
```

Each time I try to set X over 2 per small instance, the initialization fails, from which I conclude, that hadoop allocated 800m of memory per map task. To me that seems too excessive. I'd like it to be 400m tops.

How do I tell hadoop to use less memory for each map task?

Comment: You can specify how much memory each JVM should use but you have to run each task in its own process to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [mapred.child.java.opts](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/mapred-default.html) property. It's defaulted to -Xmx200m, which means 200MB of heap for each of the map/reduce task.

Looks like [EC2 small](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) has 1.7 GB memory. Here is the memory with the default settings by the Hadoop processes on the TaskTracker node. Thanks to ["Hadoop : The Definitive Guide"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do)

Datanode 1,000 MB
Tasktracker 1,000 MB
Tasktracker child map task 400 MB (2 * 200 MB)
Tasktracker child map task 400 MB (2 * 200 MB)

Total's to 2,800MB.

On top of this, there is the OS memory. Either pickup a nicer configuration or change the default settings. FYI, here is the [recommendation](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/03/clouderas-support-team-shares-some-basic-hardware-recommendations/) on the H/W configuration for the different nodes.